# Loading a file and processing it asynchronously in WinRT

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

In Visual Studio 11, I am build a HTML5 Metro application that reads and processes a file on initialization.  I have the following code:

```
var ws = Windows.Storage;

Debug.enableFirstChanceException(true);
var myDataSource = {};

var id = function (elementID) {
    return document.getElementById(elementID);
}

WinJS.Namespace.define('ToDoToday', {
    id: id,
});

function initialize() {
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFileAsync("taskList.todo", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)

.then(function (file) {
    return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
})

.then(function (stream) {
    var inputStream = stream.getInputStreamAt(0);
    var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream);

    var size = stream.size;
    if (size > 0) {
        reader.loadAsync(size).then(function(){
            myDataSource = reader.readString(size);
        })
    }
})
.then(function () {
    WinJS.Namespace.defineWithParent(ToDoToday, 'Tasks', {
        data: myDataSource,
    })
})
.then(function () {
    WinJS.UI.processAll()
})
.then(function () {
    var basicListView = WinJS.UI.getControl(document.getElementById("taskChecklist"));
    basicListView.dataSource = ToDoToday.Tasks.data;
    basicListView.refresh;
});
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
```

The initialize function never loads the file. Because of the chained thens, the debugger doesn't return anything useful.  A breakpoint on the openAsync never is hit.

The eventual error is on the databind:

JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createListBinding'

The binding appears to work just fine if I don't read from a file.

I am sure my problem is a functional misunderstanding of how to chain async calls, and a second set of eyes can't hurt.

Comment: If you download & run the JavaScript version of the [File access sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597), click the "Create file" button to create `sample.txt`, and re-run the app with a breakpoint set on line 152 of `program.js`, is the breakpoint hit?

Comment: Yes. I have restructured the program a lot. Now I am getting a different error (the myDataSource is just being reported as empty when I go to bind). Gonna follow that for a bit.  Will report back.

Comment: Same error eventually. Bummed.

Comment: You should also wrap your code in an imediate funcion to not polute the global scope. (function (){ //code here })();